# how to rename file in a directory using python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have a file named "x.mkv" in a folder named "export". X could be anything.. it's not named exactly X, it's just file with some name.
I want to rename the file to "Movie1 x [720p].mkv". I want to keep the file's original name and add Movie1 as prefix and [720p] as a suffix.
There is just one file in the folder, nothing more.
How do I do so?
I tried using variables in os.rename and i failed.. this is what I used :

```
import os
w = os.listdir("C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/New_folder/export")
s = '[Movie1]' + w + '[720p]'
os.rename(w,s)
```

What I'm trying to do is... get the file name from the folder, as there is and will be only 1 file, so, this seems appropriate.
saving the fetch results in 'w' and then using another variable 's' and adding prefix and suffix. Then at the end, I fail at using the variables in '`os.rename`' command.

Comment: You really should try *something* before asking. Googling "rename file in python" probably returns some good results.

Comment: well, I did.. and I failed.. that's why I asked.. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original won't work for a few reasons:

1. `os.listdir()` returns a list and not a string so your string concatenation will fail.
2. `os.rename()` will have trouble renaming the file unless the path is given or you change the cwd.

I'd suggest the following code:

```
import os
path="C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/New_folder/export/"
w = os.listdir(path)
#since there is only one file in directory it will be first in list
#split the filename to separate the ext from the rest of the filename
splitfilename=w[0].split('.')
s = '[Movie1]' + '.'.join(splitfilename[:-1]) + '[720p].'+splitfilename[-1]
os.rename(path+w[0],path+s)
```

Comment: if your filenames only have a period before the extension you could use splitfilename[0] where I've used the join to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
def my_rename(path, name, extension, prefix, suffix):
    os.rename(path + '/' +          old_name          + '.' + extension,
              path + '/' + prefix + old_name + suffix + '.' + extension)

my_rename('/something/export', 'x', 'mkv', 'Movie1 ', ' [720p]')
```

Comment: thanx.. but, like I said.. the name isn't "x" ... 'x' means the name could be anything... it's not particularly x.. I don't know the name of the file...

Comment: @user2408212 Right, so replace 'x' with whatever happens to be the name of your file. I put the code into a function so you can call it with different parameters depending on what exactly you need to do. If your problem is that you don't know how to *get* the name of the file, you should say so (and add specific details) in your question.